# How to remove additional text and spaces from batch output file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to collect the ICCID from multiple devices at my work.

I'm able to collect and output the ICCID but not able to remove all character to the left of  the device.txt contents, leaving only the 15 digit number.

So far I was able to create a batch file to collect the ICCID and output to device.txt file.

```
@echo off

(
%windir%\sysnative\cmd.exe /c netsh.exe mbn show interfaces | find "Device Id"

) > C:\Users\Test\Pictures\device.txt
```

This is what shows in the output file:
`Device Id: 990001234567890`

I need it to only output the number in the device.txt file:
`990001234567890`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to execute `netsh.exe` directly - no need for `cmd.exe /c`.

Use `FOR /F` to parse the output of the command as follows:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%A in (
  'netsh.exe mbn show interfaces ^| find "Device Id"'
) do >"C:\Users\Test\Pictures\device.txt" echo %%A
```

`delims=:` specifies to break the line into tokens at every `:`. The `tokens=2` specifies to take the 2nd token.

The output will have leading whitespace. To eliminate the whitespace, throw in an extra simple FOR loop:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%A in (
  'netsh.exe mbn show interfaces ^| find "Device Id"'
) do for %%B in (%%A) do >"C:\Users\Test\Pictures\device.txt" echo %%B
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to put me on the right track, but the command after netsh.exe mbn show interfaces( **| find "Device Id"**) is preventing the output file. When I remove **| find "Device Id"** it does the output but does not show the correct info in device.txt

Comment: You could do `"tokens=3 delims=: "` to use both space and colon as delimiters to eliminate the leading space.  There is a space between the colon and double quote.

Comment: Looks like I was missing an ^ before the | find "Device Id".

Comment: @JeffB - No, ***I was*** missing the `^`. All fixed in the answer. Thanks

Comment: @avery_larry - Yes, I thought of that. But if ever parsing more than 1 line and the number of words in the name varies, then the token position of the value would not be constant. I decided to give a more generic method.

Comment: If you can't rely on the output of a single command to be uniform, then your code -- *any* code for that matter -- will already have problems assuming a single `:` will always precede the desired part of the output.